# Sending parameters with Pycurl to FB api

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to do this curl request with PyCurl from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.4)

```
curl -G \
-d "date_preset=last_7_days" \
-d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<AD_CAMPAIGN_ID>/insights"
```

With the following code:

```
import pycurl
campaign_id = 'xxxxxx'
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/2.4/campaign_id/insights?access_token=access_token")
c.perform()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Unknown path components: \/6012304320061\/insights","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the version letter before version number:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/campaign_id/insights?access_token=access_token"
```